# Activeadmin stops my jQuery working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm using jquery drag and drop in my app and it works fine.

I then added activeadmin and it stops my jquery working.

I get this error

```
$(".draggable_article_image").draggable is not a function
```

If I remove this line from active_admin.js

```
//= require active_admin/base
```

it starts working again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at the [activeadmin base manifest file](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/base.js) you'll see where the additional jquery load is called. The last call in the base manifest is to the activeadmin application manifest. Therefore there is an easy way to bypass the unwanted additional jquery load.

Change this line in you application's /app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js:

```
//= require active_admin/base
```

To

```
//= require active_admin/application
```

That way active admin's javascript code will be loaded without reloading jquery.

Within the /admin space, active admin loads active_admin.js without loading application.js, so you need to load application.js there too. To work, you need to make active admin load application.js before active_admin.js. Add this to config/initializers/active_admin.rb:

```
current_javascripts = config.javascripts.clone
config.clear_javascripts! 
config.register_javascript 'application.js'
current_javascripts.reverse.each{|j| config.register_javascript j}
```

However, note that for this to work seamlessly, you may need all these declarations in your app's application.js manifest:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Also as application.js is being loaded within active admin, you need to manage any namespace conflicts yourself.

Comment: `/Users/hamdan/Projects/ruby/onemob/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:19:in `block in <main>': undefined method `reverse' for #<Set: {"active_admin.js"}> (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 11):

Try moving your *active_admin.js* file to the **vendor/assets/javascripts** folder of your Rails project : you should be fine.

Please let us know if it helped someone!

Regards

Comment: Much simpler solution. Works.

Comment: Worked for me as well :D after 5 years of solution

Comment: Indeed, it fixes the problem, but how? Because the file will be loaded even in that directory, so the jQuery also. I don't really get it, it's about call order?

Answer (score -1):

I had an error with the code above, so I tweaked mine a bit:

active admin init:

```
  config.clear_javascripts!
  config.register_javascript 'admin/active_admin.js'

  current_javascripts = config.javascripts.clone
  config.clear_javascripts!
  config.register_javascript 'application.js'
  current_javascripts.each{ |j| config.register_javascript j }
```

active admin js

```
  //= require active_admin/base
```

That's it!