# Chosen-rails for active admin form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to custumise an item creation on active_admin page. Right now what i have is a bunch of checkboxes for, for example, the feature color. What I would like to do is to have some sort of filter so as you type, those chekboxes can be filtered. It doesn't matter if they're checkboxes, selects, or whatever.

I've been advise to use `chosen-rails`. Right now this is what I have:

in my item.rb:

```
PropertyType.find_each do |pt|
        f.input :property_values, label: pt.display_name,  as: :select, collection: pt.property_values.order(name: :asc, display_name: :asc).load , multiple: true, input_html: { class: 'chosen-select' }
      end
```

in my application.js:

```
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require active_admin
```

in my application.css:

```
 *= require chosen
```

in my active_admin.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.chosen-select').chosen({
    allow_single_deselect: true,
    no_results_text: 'No results matched',
    width: '200px'
  });

});
```

and, finally, in my gemfile:

```
gem 'chosen-rails'.
```

But chosen doesn't seem to be doing its magic. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: seems like I've seen it before.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26914785/activeadmin-add-filter-to-form/26925717#26925717

Comment: yeah actually I copied that syntax from that question because it said it was working to him. but it isn't for me. what i'm missing is the correct display when i click in order to type into the input. Like no css or js is being loaded, not sure

Comment: Is it not working in development or in production?

Comment: development. didn't even try in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do in order to load your styles is add the following line to your active_admin.rb (initializer):

```
config.register_stylesheet 'active_admin_custom.css'
```

And there you should add all the styles you want. otherwise it will overlap with your regular css.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveAdmin loads its own JavaScript components which can cause problems with the host apps JavaScript environment. For example:

[Activeadmin stops my jQuery working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788304/activeadmin-stops-my-jquery-working/)

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Include-javascript-before-the-rest-of-the-active_admin-javascripts

You may well have to register chosen in the ActiveAdmin config and alter the load order.